# How can i use a javafx application instead of an html page in a J2EE project?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm actually not good at CSS at all, I really have a hard time with positioning element but I'm fairly good at JavaFX, I've been learning it for a few months now so I thought instead of wasting time on HTML and CSS I can focus on making a more appealing JSP with JavaFX but I haven't really found any good article or tutorial that could help. So is there a way for me to actually use JavaFX in a JSP web page?

Answer (score 1):

Although I highly recommend that you learn CSS and HTML, you can read this [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm) about the deployment of JavaFX applications.